# Obtaining fields from within ACF group as vars

Tags: html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to obtain values from an ACF `group` but unable to obtain them through two approaches:

Here is how my `ACF fields` are set up for reference:

[image]

**Approach 1:**

```html
<?php

$welcome_screen_content = get_field('welcome_screen_content'); // type: group

if( $welcome_screen_content ):
  $title = get_field('title');
endif;


echo $title; // prints nothing

?>
```

**Approach 2:**

```html
<?php

if( have_rows('welcome_screen_content') ):
  while( have_rows('welcome_screen_content') ): the_row();

  $title = get_sub_field('title');

  echo $title; // prints nothing

  endwhile;
endif;

?>
```

On my post template, `title` does have a value:

[image]

So unsure why in both attempts, echoing `$title` does nothing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `get_field` on a [group](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/group/), Advanced Custom Fields returns an associative array containing the group's fields. So to get the title inside, you do this:

```
$welcome_screen_content = get_field('welcome_screen_content'); // type: group

if( $welcome_screen_content ):
  $title = $welcome_screen_content['title'];
endif;
```

Approach 1 doesn't work as expected because `get_field('title')` asks ACF to get a field at the same level as the "welcome_screen_content" group.

Approach 2 doesn't work as expected because `get_subfield` is for use with [Repeater or Flexible Content Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_sub_field/).

Answer (score 0):

I came across this [helper function to get values from a field group](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/how-to-get-field-data-from-a-group-inside-a-group/#post-133630) and found it handy.

You use it like so: `get_group_field( '{group field name}', '{sub field name}' );`